# Finding the lengths of this triangle?

Tags: triangles

[image: Triangle i am trying to solve]

please help, i'm to answer the question. The length of AB is 14.67106m.
Please give working outs.

Comment: What did you try? How did you find AB? Try Pythagoras for AE^2=CE^2+AC^2

Comment: HINT: You can use pythagoras for both

Comment: @Inkaho, I guess you have left out a great deal of information - 1. Is it a continuation of part (a) and (b) (the question is part (c)) where more details about the figure are given? 2. Is M mid point of AC?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: (i)(a)$AC=26m,CE=3.2m$ using this and Pythagoras theorem in $\triangle ACE$, can something be inferred about AE?

(b) M is not given as midpoint of AC. You have already found $AB$ (assuming that its correct), you know $BM=10-3.2$, again using Pythagoras theorem, can something be inferred about $AM$ (and hence $MC=FE$)? Use $FE,FB$ in $\triangle FEB$ to find $BE$.

(ii) Knowing $AE,AG,GE$, using $\triangle AGE$, you can find $\angle AEG$ and knowing $FE,BF,BE$, using $\triangle FBE$, you can find $\angle BEF$ and hence $\angle AEB$

Comment: Thank you all for the tips, I have now figured it out. I can't believe I didn't see it before.